# can't update ubuntu 14.04 using apt-get update

Tags: 14.04

when i try to update ubuntu using
 *sudo apt-get update*

it give error

> E: Type 'OK' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/enpass.list

it started after i try to install enpass in my system.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/enpass.list. This file is probably malformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo rm -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d/enpass.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -s http://repo.sinew.in/keys/enpass-linux.key | sudo apt-key add
echo "deb http://repo.sinew.in/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/enpass.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install enpass
```